# Header will not span entire page/extra space on right

Tags: html, css

Hey guys I'm building my first website and I cannot figure how to get rid of the extra space on the right which brings up the horizontal scrollbar. The site is http://qtsocial.com/accounts/login/ ... If you can look at the css and give me a clue I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
body {
    background: url(http://qtsocial.com/static/images/body-bkg.png) repeat scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    margin: 0pt auto;
    width: 100%;
}

#header {
    background: url(http://qtsocial.com/static/images/hdr-bkg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 181px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#logo {
    background-image: url(http://qtsocial.com/static/images/QTlogo.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 88px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 25px;
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation{
    height:40px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the DIV with id of `logo` set to 100% width (which is setting it to the page width) then you're indenting it by 25px. Change the width of `#logo` on line 25 of login.css to be the width of the background image you're using (299px).

Answer (score 0):

## Logo is too wide

Inside `#logo` Change `width: 100%;` to `width: 299px;` (the actual width of the image)

Answer (score 0):

Your logo div is whats causing it.

It is 100% of the width, but this does not include the 25px of the left of it, thus it is overflowing 25px to the right of your window.

Change the width of the logo div to the width of your logo image, and it won't overflow to the right.

Comment: Padding won't affect `background-image`

Comment: Realized that 30 seconds after I posted, and then fixed it.